# ScrollView no se desplaza hacia arriba

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando generar una venta de mensajes que se desplaza hacia abajo según inserto texto en un `TextView` multilinea, pero el `Scrollview` no funciona cuando intento moverlo hacia arriba para ver los mensajes anteriores.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/idChat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

       <TextView
            style="@style/chat"
            android:id="@+id/textoChat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:maxLines="50"
            android:text="" />

</ScrollView>
```

Y la parte lógica:

```
public void mensaje (View vista){
    String msg = getResources().getString(R.string.msg1);
    Chat(msg + System.getProperty ("line.separator"));
}

public void Chat(String msg){
    TextView lista = findViewById(R.id.textoChat);
    lista.append(msg);

}
```

Comment: Vale pregunta tonta, no hace falta ScrollView cuando se usa un TextView, basta con añadir la propiedad scrollbars.

Comment: Ya tienes un ScrollView pero si el TextView no tiene contenido que suficiente no se activa, ya que no es necesario. @M.J.D

Answer (score 0):

En realidad ya tienes un `ScrollView` para este propósito,

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/idChat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

       <TextView
            style="@style/chat"
            android:id="@+id/textoChat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:maxLines="50"
            android:text="" />

</ScrollView>
```

Si el contenido dentro del `ScrollView` en este caso el Texto dentro del `TextView` no tiene contenido suficiente, el `ScrollView` no se activa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y solo se muestra cuando el contenido es mayor al area de tu `ScrollView` y aplicas y realizas "scroll". No es necesario agregar la propiedad `android:scrollbars="vertical"` ya que se activa la barra de "scroll" automáticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]